# Is it a bad practice to bind ngModel to @Input property?

Tags: angular

Here is a simple component that receives an `inputValue` and binds it to an input field:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-input',
  template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="inputValue">
  `,
})
export class CustomInputComponent {
  @Input() inputValue: string;
}
```

I'm curious if its fine to do so, or maybe it's better to do it this way with `localInputValue`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-input',
  template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="localInputValue">
  `,
})
export class CustomInputComponent {
  @Input() inputValue: string;
  localInputValue:string;

  ngOnInit(){
  this.localInputValue = this.inputValue
  
  }
}
```

I understand that in the first case, if Input changes, it would set value of the input field to that value, and that might erase user's input. However, if the Input doesn't change is there any convention regarding if the first or second way should be used/prefered?

Comment: Depends on your use case

Comment: @AndrewAllen could you provide more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this approach it's that the change of the input not change the variable in the "parent", and a change of the variable in parent not change the value in child

You can use setters

```
export class CustomInputComponent {
  get localInputValue(){
    return this.inputValue
  }
  set localInputValue(value:string)
  {
     this.inputValue=value;
     this.inputValueChange.emit(value)
  }

  @Input() inputValue: string;
  @Output() inputValueChange:eventEmitter<string>=new eventEmitter<string>()
```

Well, if you needn't two-way-binding, you can use Input, in this way, when change in parent, change in child.

```
export class CustomInputComponent {
  localInputValue:string="";
  @Input('inputValue') set _(value:string){
     this.localInputValue=value;
  }
```

You can see in action in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vo3tf2?file=src%2Fmain.ts). See that in child2 when change in child2, not change in parent, but when you change from parent change in child